# XML to dataframe How to get a default value if node does not exist

Tags: xml, r

In R, I want to parse an XML file using the XML package. The actual file is taken from Eurostats REST service. You will find a link to the actual data at the end of the question. The relevant structure of the file is as follows:

```
doc <- xmlParse( # needed to run example
'<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Series>
  <Obs>
    <ObsDimension value="2009"/>
    <ObsValue value="NaN"/>
    <Attributes>
      <Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="na"/>
    </Attributes>
  </Obs>
  <Obs>
    <ObsDimension value="2006"/>
    <ObsValue value="NaN"/>
    <Attributes>
      <Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="na"/>
    </Attributes>
  </Obs>
  <Obs>
    <ObsDimension value="2009"/>
    <ObsValue value="43.75"/>
  </Obs>
  <Obs>
    <ObsDimension value="2006"/>
    <ObsValue value="NaN"/>
    <Attributes>
      <Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="na"/>
      <Value id="OBS_FLAG" value="e"/>
    </Attributes>
  </Obs>
</Series>
') # needed to run example
```

So there is a Dimension and a Value for each Obs node. In addition there are two optional Attributes which are identified by an id attribute  OBS_STATUS or OBS_FLAG. I want to parse this structure into so that `NA` is used if the attributes are not present. The result should look like this:

```
  dimension value status flag
1      2009   NaN     na <NA>
2      2006   NaN     na <NA>
3      2009 43.75   <NA> <NA>
4      2006   NaN     na    e
```

I prepared the following code which obviouly fails, because the columns are not of equal length.

```
library(XML)
data.frame(dimension = xpathSApply(doc,"//ObsDimension",xmlGetAttr,"value"),
           value = xpathSApply(doc,"//ObsValue",xmlGetAttr,"value"),
           status = xpathSApply(doc,
                                "//Attributes/Value[@id='OBS_STATUS']",
                                xmlGetAttr,"value"),
           flag = xpathSApply(doc,
                                "//Attributes/Value[@id='OBS_FLAG']",
                                xmlGetAttr,"value"))
```

Is there a good way of defining an optional value if a specified node is not present? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Addendum** added after receiving Answer by @MrFlick.
The data I actually need to parse can be loaded with the following code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
file <- "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/data/cdh_e_fos/..PC.FOS1.BE/?startperiod=2005&endPeriod=2013"
content <- getURL(file, httpheader = list('User-Agent' = 'R-Agent'))
root <- xmlRoot(xmlInternalTreeParse(content, useInternalNodes = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Take 1

Here is one possible strategy. There is a nice `xmlToDataFrame` function, but your data isn't quite in the right format for that. I think it would be easiest to transform your data into a more suitable format and then use that function. Here's one such transformation

```
trn<-newXMLDoc()
addChildren(trn, newXMLNode("data"))

for(x in getNodeSet(doc, "//Obs")) {
    row<-newXMLNode("row")
    for( z in getNodeSet(x, ".//*[not(*)]")) {
        li <- newXMLNode(xmlGetAttr(z, "id", xmlName(z)))
        addChildren(li, newXMLTextNode(xmlGetAttr(z, "value",NA)))
        addChildren(row, li)
    }
    addChildren(xmlRoot(trn), row)
}
```

We create a new XML document that ends up looking like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <row>
    <ObsDimension>2009</ObsDimension>
    <ObsValue>NaN</ObsValue>
    <OBS_STATUS>na</OBS_STATUS>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ObsDimension>2006</ObsDimension>
    <ObsValue>NaN</ObsValue>
    <OBS_STATUS>na</OBS_STATUS>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ObsDimension>2009</ObsDimension>
    <ObsValue>43.75</ObsValue>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ObsDimension>2006</ObsDimension>
    <ObsValue>NaN</ObsValue>
    <OBS_STATUS>na</OBS_STATUS>
    <OBS_FLAG>e</OBS_FLAG>
  </row>
</data>
```

and we can call

```
xmlToDataFrame(trn)
```

to get

```
  ObsDimension ObsValue OBS_STATUS OBS_FLAG
1         2009      NaN         na     <NA>
2         2006      NaN         na     <NA>
3         2009    43.75       <NA>     <NA>
4         2006      NaN         na        e
```

Yes I use some ugly for loops, but that's really to make sure we create a value for each `Obs`  node. That's really the primary unit of data so you can't skip over it when grabbings nodes with xpath. You could build the data.frame directly in the loop, but i prefer to let `xmlToDataFrame` take care of the fact that each node has a potentially different number of elements.

## Take 2

If you really need to specify a default value when a Node doesn't exist, you can create a function similr to `xmlGetAttr` but one that also checks for a node as well. Here is such a helper function.

```
xmlGetNodeAttr <- function(n, xp, attr, default=NA) {
    ns<-getNodeSet(n, xp)
    if(length(ns)<1) {
        return(default)
    } else {
        sapply(ns, xmlGetAttr, attr, default)
    }
}
```

We could apply it to your data with

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(xmlChildren(xmlRoot(doc)), function(x) {
    data.frame(
        dimension=xmlGetNodeAttr(x, "./ObsDimension","value",NA),
        value=xmlGetNodeAttr(x, "./ObsValue","value",NA),
        status=xmlGetNodeAttr(x, "./Attributes/Value[@id='OBS_STATUS']","value",NA),
        flag=xmlGetNodeAttr(x, "./Attributes/Value[@id='OBS_FLAG']","value",NA)
    )
}))
```

which produces the same result. Here we still must loop over the `Obs` nodes individually because there is no way to force a match for each `Obs` with xpath.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer which works fine on the simplified data in the Question. However, the data I actually need to parse is more complex (see edited question), so I would prefer if there is a solution that provides an optional value when the specified node is not present. Working on the original xml data before parsing is an alternative approach that I didn't have on my radar so far. +1 for that hint.

Comment: I don't know what else you want. This method would appear to work just fine on that other data. In xapth, there's no such thing as a NA value for "no match". You either get a node or you don't. The `xmlGetAttr` function does allow you to specify a default value, but at that point a node must exist.

Comment: I've updated with another method that maybe is closer to what you were imagining.

Comment: Fantastic! This is indeed what I was looking for. Just needed to add Namespaces ins the `xpath` expressions and as an argument to `xmlGetNodeAttr`. Thanks for your help (and patience).